# Combine two MySQL tables into one (plus arithmetic)

Tags: mysql

This should be a simple problem but I can't seem to find an exact solution. This is basically what I have:

table_1:

```
id*   scenario*    val1     val2
---   --------     -----    ------
AC1    1            2        0
AC2    1            1        0 
AC1    2            4        0
AC2    2            3        0
```

table_2:

```
id*     val3
---     ------
AC1       4
AC2       6
```

All I want to do is update val2 of table_1 where scenario = 1 with values from table_2 with matching id but I want it to equal val1 + val3 (I don't know how to make this less obfuscated). So for this example I want table_1 to become:

```
id*   scenario*    val1     val2
---   --------     ------   --------
AC1    1            2        6
AC2    1            1        7 
AC1    2            4        0
AC2    2            3        0
```

I think this can be done with a simple MySQL statement but I don't know how to structure it with a condition for the first table ("INSERT INTO table_1 WHERE scenario=1 SELECT..."??) and the arithmetic of two columns from two different tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
UPDATE table_1 
SET val2 = val1 + 
    (SELECT val3 FROM table_2
     WHERE id = table_1.id
     LIMIT 0,1)
WHERE scenario = 1
```

Answer (score 2):

A pretty straight forward and readable JOIN will do it;

```
UPDATE table_1 t1
JOIN table_2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
SET t1.val2 = t1.val1 + t2.val3
WHERE scenario = 1;
```

Demo [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cdbc2/3).

Comment: Thanks for fast reply! SQL Fiddle looks like a very helpful tool to help me understand the logic.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you will hard code the scenario value because otherwise there is no way to link table_2 data to a table_1 scenairo.

So I would do something like:

```
UPDATE table_1 set val2 = val1 + (select val3 from FROM table_2 WHERE table_2.id = table_1.id)
WHERE scenario = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
UPDATE table_1 a join table_2 b on a.id = b.id
set a.val2 = a.val1 + b.val3 
where a.scenario = 1
```

Comment: thnx for pointing that, i was testing it on sql server and didn't notice that question is for mysql.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query -

```
UPDATE table_1 t1
  JOIN table_2 t2
    ON t1.id = t2.id
  SET t1.val2 = t1.val1 + t2.val3
WHERE t1.scenario = 1
```